# Eclipse Marketplace will not open

Tags: eclipse, installation, virtual-machine

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iw6U.png)

see image for error:

JRE8 is installed on the system, this is VM environment where eclipse is installed

Need eclipse market place to work so that StatET 4.8 can be installed

Please help

Have tried researching error but to no avail, I understand its missing a cert but have no idea where to get cert needed and how to implement

Comment: Ok, but which version of Eclipse is this? Which version of JRE8, down to the patch level? On how current an O.S.? And why the mention of JRE8 when StatET 4.8 requires Java 17 and Eclipse 2023-06?

Comment: The missing certificate should be part of the Java you use to run Eclipse. Probably your Eclipse and the Java you are running it with is way too old. Does it work with the current Eclipse which contains Java 17? Or are you behind a proxy? If this does not help, please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.